# Вызов процедуры у объекта через ссылку на него

Tags: lazarus, delphi

Пишу векторный графический редактор на `Lazarus`. Есть иерархия классов типа `Shape` и иерархия классов типа `Tool`. В данный момент работаю над инструментом выделения `TSelectionTool`. Он описан так:

```
TTool = class //базовый класс для инструментов
  protected
    FTag: integer;
    FTop: integer;
    FIsActivated: Boolean;
    function CreateTrackBar(params: parametres_tb): TTrackBar;
    function CreateLabel(capt: string): TLabel;
    function CreateComboBox(k, sel: integer): TComboBox;
  public
    constructor Create(params: parametres; t: integer); virtual;
    procedure MouseDown(p: TPoint; var list: TShapeList; canv: TCanvas); virtual;
    procedure MouseMove(p: TPoint; shape: TBasicShape; canv: TCanvas); virtual;
    procedure MouseUp; virtual;
    procedure SetParametres(var params: parametres); virtual;
    procedure InitParamsUI(var panel: TPanel; params: parametres); virtual;
    procedure FreeUI; virtual;
    property IsActivated: Boolean read FIsActivated write FIsActivated;
  end;

TSelectionTool = class(TTool)
  private
    FSelected: TShapeArrayP;
  public
    procedure MouseDown(p: TPoint; var list: TShapeList; canv: TCanvas); override;
  end;
```

Далее процедура нажатие клавиши у инструмента выделения:

```
procedure TSelectionTool.MouseDown(p: TPoint; var list: TShapeList; canv: TCanvas);
begin
  inherited;
  if list.GetContainedShape(p) <> nil then
    begin
      SetLength(FSelected, Length(FSelected)+1);
      FSelected[High(FSelected)] := list.GetContainedShape(p);
      FSelected[High(FSelected)]^.Mark(canv);
    end;
end;
```

list - объект класса TShapeList, содержащий в себе динамический массив нарисованных шейпов. Описан так:

```
TShapeArray = Array of TBasicShape;
  TShapeArrayP = Array of ^TBasicShape;
  TBasicShapeClass = class of TBasicShape;
  TShapeList = class
  private
    FShapes: TShapeArray;
    FIsChanged: Boolean;
    FIsSaved: Boolean;
    function GetShapes: TShapeArray;
  public
    constructor Create;
    function GetContainedShape(p: TPoint): Pointer;
    procedure AddBasicShape(p: TPoint; pen: TPenStyle; b: TBrushStyle; col: TColorArray; w, t: integer);
    procedure AddRoundRect(p: TPoint; pen: TPenStyle; b: TBrushStyle; col: TColorArray; w, r: integer);
    procedure DrawAll(canv: TCanvas);
    procedure Save(fileName: String);
    procedure Load(var f: Textfile);
    procedure ClearAll(canv: TCanvas);
    property Shapes: TShapeArray read FShapes write FShapes;
    property IsChanged: Boolean read FIsChanged write FIsChanged;
    property IsSaved: Boolean read FIsSaved write FIsSaved;
  end;
```

Процедура `GetContainedShape(p: TPoint): Pointer` возвращает указатель на шейп, который содержит данную точку:

```
function TShapeList.GetContainedShape(p: TPoint): Pointer;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to High(FShapes) do
    if FShapes[i].isBelong(p) then
      begin
        Result := FShapes[i];
        exit;
      end;
end;
```

Две функции у класса TBasicShape - принадлежность точки фигуре (isBelong) и получение "объемлющего" прямоугольника (прямоугольника, в который помещается весь шейп):

```
function TBasicShape.IsBelong(p: TPoint): Boolean;
var
  r: TRect;
begin
  r := GetContainRect;
  Result := (p.X >= r.Left) and (p.X <= r.Right) and (p.Y <= r.Top) and (p.Y >= r.Bottom);
end;   
function TBasicShape.GetContainRect: TRect;
begin
  Result.Top := Min(FStart.y, FFinish.y);
  Result.Bottom := Max(FStart.y, FFinish.y);
  Result.Left := Min(FStart.x, FFinish.x);
  Result.Right := Max(FStart.x, FFinish.x);
end;
```

Процедура Mark (выделить, отметить) - рисует рамку вокруг шейпа:

```
procedure TBasicShape.Mark(canv: TCanvas);
begin
  canv.Brush.Style := bsClear;
  canv.Pen.Style := psDash;
  canv.Pen.Color := clBlack;
  canv.Pen.Width := 2;
  canv.Rectangle(GetContainRect);
end;
```

Теперь, собственно, проблема. Программа ломается на выполнении строки

```
Result.Top := Min(FStart.y, FFinish.y); (function GetContainRect).
```

Если не вызывать эту функцию (`GetContainRect`), а просто указать координаты (любые, главное, чтобы было видно, что что-то отрисовывается), то прямоугольник почему-то рисуется всегда (не зависимо от того, кликнули ли на шейп либо мимо него). Хотел использовать функцию `PtInRect`, но Lazarus почему-то её знает. (Может быть я просто не подключил модуль, в котором она находится?) Мне так кажется, что ошибка в вызове процедуры `Mark` через `^`. Подскажите, как исправить. <br> `TBasicShape = class
  protected
    FStart: TPoint;
    FColors: TColorArray;
    FFinish: TPoint;
    FWidth: Integer;
    FPenStyle: TPenStyle;
    FBrushStyle: TBrushStyle;
    function GetStart: TPoint;
    function GetColors: TColorArray;
    function GetFinish: TPoint;
    function GetWidth: Integer;
    function GetPoint(var s: string): TPoint;
    function GetSubStr(var s: string): string;
    function IsBelong(p: TPoint): Boolean;
    procedure SetPen(width: integer; color: TColor; style: TPenStyle; canv: TCanvas);
    procedure SetBrush(color: TColor; style: TBrushStyle; canv: TCanvas);
  public
    constructor Create(p: TPoint; pen: TPenStyle; b: TBrushStyle; col: TColorArray; w: integer); virtual;
    constructor Load(var s: String); virtual;
    function GetContainRect: TRect;
    function Save: String; virtual;
    procedure Draw(canv: TCanvas); virtual; abstract;
    procedure SetFinish(p: TPoint); virtual;
    procedure Mark(canv: TCanvas);
    property Start: TPoint read GetStart;
    property Colors: TColorArray read FColors;
    property Finish: TPoint read GetFinish write FFinish;
    property Width: integer read GetWidth write FWidth;
  end;`

Comment: Что скрывается за FStart и FFinish ? Ссылки на шейпы? Попробуйте их разыменовывать и/или приводить к нужному типу.

Comment: FStart, FFinish - начальная и конечная точки шейпа соответственно.

Comment: Дайте описание TBasicShape

Comment: @MultiTeemer
В `FStart` и `FFinish` что-то есть в момент когда вы к ним обращаетесь? Вы можете гарантировать, что в момент вызова `GetContainRect` эти поля проинициализированны? И что объект класса `TBasicShape` к которому вы обращаетесь создан?